# assign styles to jsp tags dynamically using jquery

Tags: jquery, jsp, tags, styles

Trying to assign the styles to jsp tags dynamically using Jquery.

```
       <script>
        $(document).ready(function(){
            var color=$("#cscolour").val();    
            if(color!=null){
                $("#color").css('background-image', 'none');
                $("#color").css({"background-color":color});
            }
        });
        </script>

        <body>
        <input type="hidden" name="cscolour" id="cscolour" value='<%= csticColour %>'/>
  <h1 id='<%= csticColour %>'> welcome </h1>
        </body>
```

Comment: Please be specific question is not clear

Comment: Why not just create css classes and assign them to the jsp tags? They will have the classes when they are loaded in the DOM.

Comment: Do your "jsp" tags (they should be html tags in the end) have the id "color"?

Comment: Where is the HTML element with id "color"?

Comment: Why are you setting the id of the h1 to the value of the input? That doesn't make sense.

Comment: as per the requirement, each h1 tag should be in different color. so i'm setting the id for each h1.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I hope you are trying like this,

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".colors").each(function( index ) {
        $("#"+this.id).css({"background-color": this.id});
    });
});
```

And HTML part,

```
<input type="hidden" name="cscolour" id="cscolour" value="YELLOW"/>
<h1 id="YELLOW" class="colors">vk</h1>
 <h1 id="RED" class="colors">vk1</h1>
  <h1 id="GREEN" class="colors">vk2</h1>
```

In [Live](http://jsfiddle.net/dtjv2/3/.). Please read the instruction in SO before ask your questions.

Please check the **updated** part.
As per your new comments, I added the following.

```
<h1 class="YELLOW">vk</h1>
<h1 class="RED">vk1</h1>
<h1 class="GREEN">vk2</h1>
<h1 class="YELLOW">vk3</h1>
<h1 class="GREEN">sh1</h1>
<h1 class="RED">sh2</h1>
```

And the script part is,

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   $("h1").each(function( index ) {
     $("."+$(this).attr("class")).css({"background-color": $(this).attr("class")});
   });
});
```

Seel the [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Vinoth_Krishnan/dtjv2/4/) here.

Comment: yes, but the color and the id is entered by the user at the time of runtime. So i want the do the same dynamically

Comment: Instead of id, you can go with class. If more than one yellow present your page will not properly respond as you think.

Comment: @VK- this is not working when we have more than one <h1> tags.

Comment: Shanmugam check [this](http://jsfiddle.net/dtjv2/3/) out. I have just used h1 for dynamic colors.

Comment: Sorry, again, if we have more that one id for the same color, its not displaying. any idea to bypass ids if its same. Pls check the link - http://jsfiddle.net/dtjv2/3/

Comment: @Shanmugam, Check [this](http://jsfiddle.net/Vinoth_Krishnan/dtjv2/4/) out. Hope you will get it this time.